# Wxpython producing error

Tags: python, wxpython, gdal

I am trying to run a progrom from the book `"Remote Sensing Raster Programming"` for calculating `NDVI from raster dataset`. Program reads two separate raster bands `NIR` and `RED` using `GDAL` and executes following equation `NDVI = (NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED)`.

But it is producing error and GUI is not openning. I am trying to learn wxPython and I will appreciate any help to sort out this problem.

Error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ndvi.py", line 189, in <module>
frame = MyFrame(None)
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ndvi.py", line 48, in __init__
self.make_fb()
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\ndvi.py", line 112, in make_fb
fileMode=wx.OPEN,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPEN'
```

Code for the program

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import wx
import wx.lib.filebrowsebutton as filebrowse
import os

# For Image Processing
import numpy
from osgeo import gdalnumeric
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdal_array
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

# Define satellite bands
redchan = ''
nirchan = ''

# Define output file name
output = ''

# Define Info Message
overview = """Vegetation Index Processing.

Calculates vegetation indices based on biophysical parameters.
NDVI: Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
NDVI = (band 2 - band 1) / (band 2 + band 1)
NDVI = (NIR - Red) / (NIR + Red)

Rouse J., Haas R., Schell J. and Deering D. (1974).
Monitoring vegetation systems in the Great Plains
with ERTS. In Proceedings of the Third Earth
Resources Technology Satellite-1 Symposium, Greenbelt."""

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self,parent, id=-1, title='Normalized Difference Vegetation Index Processing',
                        pos=(0,0),
                        size=(400,400),
                        style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE):
                wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style)
                self.lognull = wx.LogNull()
                # Input Filenames
                self.redchan = redchan
                self.nirchan = nirchan
                self.output = output
                # Construct Interface
                self.make_text()
                self.make_buttons()
                self.make_fb()
                self.mbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.mbox.Add(self.text, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.CENTER, 10)
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.mbox.Add(self.cc2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
                self.mbox.Add(self.cc3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
                self.mbox.Add(self.cc6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10)
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.mbox.Add(self.bbox, 1, wx.CENTER, 10)
                self.mbox.Add((10,10))
                self.SetSizer(self.mbox)
                self.bindEvents()

# Process Equations, Handling and saving of output
        def OnOK(self,event):
                print "red: ", self.redchan, " nir:",self.nirchan, " out:", self.output
                if(self.redchan==''):
                        self.OnFileInError()
                elif(self.nirchan==''):
                        self.OnFileInError()
                else:
                        self.redband = gdal_array.LoadFile(self.redchan)
                        self.nirband = gdal_array.LoadFile(self.nirchan)
                # NDVI
                self.result=self.ndvi(self.redband, self.nirband)

                # prepare/create output file
                tmp = gdal.Open(str(self.redchan))
                geoT = tmp.GetGeoTransform()
                proJ = tmp.GetProjection()
                tmp = None
                out = gdal_array.OpenArray(self.result )
                out.SetGeoTransform( geoT )
                out.SetProjection( proJ )
                driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' )
                driver.CreateCopy( self.output, out )
                self.Destroy()

        def ndvi( self, redchan, nirchan ):
                """
                Normalized Difference Vegetation Index
                ndvi( redchan, nirchan )
                """
                result = 1.0*( nirchan - redchan )
                result /= 1.0*( nirchan + redchan )
                return result

        def OnFileInError(self):
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self,
                                'Minimum files to add:\n\n Input files => Red and NIR \n One Output file',
                                'Error',wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
                dlg.ShowModal()
                dlg.Destroy()

        # Path+filename seek and set
        def make_fb(self):
                # get current working directory
                self.dirnm = os.getcwd()
                self.cc2 = filebrowse.FileBrowseButton(
                        self, -1, size=(50, -1), labelText='RED:',
                        startDirectory = self.dirnm,
                        fileMode=wx.OPEN,
                        changeCallback = self.fbbCallback2,
                                )
                self.cc3 = filebrowse.FileBrowseButton(
                        self, -1, size=(50, -1), labelText='NIR:',
                        startDirectory = self.dirnm,
                        fileMode=wx.OPEN,
                        changeCallback = self.fbbCallback3
                                )
                self.cc6 = filebrowse.FileBrowseButton(
                        self, -1, size=(50, -1), labelText='OUT File:',
                        startDirectory = self.dirnm,
                        fileMask='*.tif',
                        fileMode=wx.SAVE,
                        changeCallback = self.fbbCallback6
                                )
        # Collect path+filenames
        def fbbCallback2(self, evt):
                self.redchan = str(evt.GetString())
        def fbbCallback3(self, evt):
                self.nirchan = str(evt.GetString())
        def fbbCallback6(self, evt):
                self.output = str(evt.GetString())
        # Front text
        def make_text(self):
                self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, '''\n\tThis is a full Python +
                        WxPython application,\n\tprocessing NDVI through the use
                        of \n\tGDAL Python bindings and numpy''')

        # Bottom buttons
        def make_buttons(self):
                self.bbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
                # OnOK
                bmp0 = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_TICK_MARK, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (32,32))
                self.b0 = wx.BitmapButton(self, 20, bmp0, (20, 20),
                        (bmp0.GetWidth()+50, bmp0.GetHeight()+10), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
                self.b0.SetToolTip("Process")
                self.bbox.Add(self.b0,1,wx.CENTER,10)
                # OnCancel
                bmp1 = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_CROSS_MARK, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (32,32))
                self.b1 = wx.BitmapButton(self, 30, bmp1, (20, 20),
            (bmp1.GetWidth()+50, bmp1.GetHeight()+10), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
                self.b1.SetToolTip("Abort")
                self.bbox.Add(self.b1,1,wx.CENTER,10)
                # OnInfo
                bmp2 = wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_HELP, wx.ART_TOOLBAR, (32,32))
                self.b2 = wx.BitmapButton(self, 40, bmp2, (20, 20),
                        (bmp2.GetWidth()+50, bmp2.GetHeight()+10), style=wx.NO_BORDER)
                self.b2.SetToolTip("Help/Info.")
                self.bbox.Add(self.b2,1,wx.CENTER,10)

        def bindEvents(self):
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOK, self.b0)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnCancel, self.b1)
                self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnInfo, self.b2)

        def OnCloseWindow(self, event):
                self.Destroy()

        def OnCancel(self, event):
                self.Destroy()

        def OnInfo(self,event):
                dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, overview,'Help', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
                dlg.ShowModal()
                dlg.Destroy()

class MainApp(wx.App):
        def OnInit(self):
                frame = MainFrame(None)
                frame.Show(True)
                self.SetTopWindow(frame)
                return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = wx.App()
        frame = MyFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using wxPython 4 (Phoenix), then you want to use `wx.FD_OPEN` instead of `wx.OPEN`. I'm not sure why that's not in the [Migration Guide](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html) or the [Classic Vs. Phoenix](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/classic_vs_phoenix.html) page though

Comment: Thanks, the solution you provided worked perfectly :-)